# Como passar uma expressão SQL para um UPDATE pelo Zend?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend, mvc

Meu SGBD MySQL possui uma tabela chamada elementos onde um dos campos se chama `posicao` e é do tipo `int (6)`.

Preciso efetuar um update (SQL) onde o campo `posicao` deve ser atualizado com o seu próprio valor subtraindo 1 conforme a cláusula `where`. A seguinte query (SQL) executa isso:

```sql
UPDATE elementos
SET posicao = (posicao - 1)
WHERE posicao > 9
```

Convertendo essa query para uso no model, uma das tentativas que fiz foi esta, mas não rolou:

```
$db = new Application_Model_DbTable_Elemento();
$dados = array(
'posicao' => (posicao - 1)
);
$where = $db->getAdapter()->quoteInto('posicao > ?', 9);
$db->update($dados, $where);
```

Eu acredito que o problema esteja nos dados definidos no array `$dados`. Como seria a sintaxe para executar esse `UPDATE`?

Comment: No código PHP, `(posicao - 1)` deveria ser string, não? Ou vai dar erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Olá @bfavaretto. Se eu substituir (posicao - 1) por uma string o cálculo não será executado e acontecerá uma atualização incorreta na tabela, pois o campo é do tipo int (6).

Comment: Olha, não uso o Zend e pessoalmente acabaria fazendo a query na mão, mas acho que encontrei sua resposta aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267340/825789

Comment: Era isso aí mesmo @bfavaretto! Agora rolou legal. Valeu pela dica meu!

Comment: Ok, postei a solução como resposta para que possa ser útil a futuros visitantes do site.

Comment: Xi, fui rápido demais? Se quiser manter sua resposta, apago a minha.

Comment: Não @bfavaretto, está perfeito. Mais uma vez obrigadão!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi em uma [resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267340), para passar uma expressão como essa ao MySQL é necessário criar um objeto do tipo `Zend_Db_Expr`. Com isso seu código ficaria assim:

```
$db = new Application_Model_DbTable_Elemento();
$dados = array(
    'posicao' => new Zend_Db_Expr('posicao - 1')
);
$where = $db->getAdapter()->quoteInto('posicao > ?', 9);
$db->update($dados, $where);
```